# WP insert post and custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-insert-post

I have create a custom post type in my WordPress attached with a custom taxonomy.

The post collect date from the from end of the web site by using wp_insert_post().

This is my Custom post registration code:

```
$labels = array(
        'name' => 'Films',
        'singular_name' => 'Film',
        'add_new' => 'Add new',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add new film',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit film',
        'new_item' => 'New film',
        'all_items' => 'All films',
        'view_item' => 'View film',
        'search_items' => 'Search films',
        'not_found' =>  'No films found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No films found in Trash', 
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Films'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'show_in_menu' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'taxonomies' => array('film_category'),
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor'
        )
    );

    register_post_type('film', $args);
```

And this is my Custom Taxonomy registration Code:

```
$labels = array(
        'name' => 'Category',
        'singular_name' => 'Film',
        'search_items' =>  'Search Categories',
        'all_items' => 'All Categories',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent Category',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Category:',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Category', 
        'update_item' => 'Update Category',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Category',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Category Name',
        'menu_name' => 'Category'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => false,
        'capabilities' => array('manage_terms') 
    );

    register_taxonomy('film_category', array('film'), $args);
```

both are fired on init action.

And now when the end User submit the form from the front end I execute that code:

```
$post = array(
            'comment_status' => 'closed',
            'ping_status' => 'closed',
            'post_author' => 2,
            'post_content' => $_POST['synopsis'],
            'post_name' => sanitize_title($_POST['title']),
            'post_status' => 'private',
            'post_title' => $_POST['title'],
            'post_type' => 'film',
            'tax_input' => array(
                'film_category' => array(
                    $_POST['category']
                )
            )
        );

        $new_film_id = wp_insert_post($post);

        wp_set_object_terms($new_film_id, $_POST['category'], 'film_category', true);
```

In my front end form I have the "category" select field that contain the film categories. I have try to add on options values the terms ID, the terms Name and the terms Slug but it doesn't work.

the new post is generated in my custom post type, but I can't assign the film categories.

Any idea please ?

Comment: Had you checked that `$_POST['category']` contains sane data at that point? Had you tried your code in dry run with test data, without front-end part?

Comment: I check my data with print_r a step after the assignment and there is the correct data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the code that catches an processes the `$_POST` data? Is it in a template file? Or is it in a function that is run on a hook? If it's the latter, and if `taxonomy_exists()` is returning `false` as you suggest here (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45798/wp-insert-post-and-custom-taxonomy#comment58402_45810), it's possible that you're checking before `register_taxonomy` has had a chance to run. Make sure that your form-processing function is hooked to something later than `init:10`.

Comment: Boone Gorges !!!! You are just perfect !!!!!! That worked for me. Until now I called the function that save my data imediatly, and now I hooked that function on init hook and worked !! :) Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to use:

```
wp_set_object_terms($new_film_id, $_POST['category'], 'film_category', true);
```

**and** the `tax_input` array value. The <s>latter</s> former *(Please see end remark)* should be sufficient.

If `$_POST['category']` contains the term IDs, you will need to cast them as integers so they are not interpreted as slugs.

Also if `$_POST['category']` is an *array* then using `array($_POST['category'])` will be causing the problems. Try:

```
 //Cas as array
 $terms = isset($_POST['category']) ? (array) $_POST['category'] : array();

 //Cast array values as integers if $_POST['category'] contains IDs
 $terms = array_map('intval',$terms);

 $post = array(
      //other arguments

      'tax_input' => array(
            'film_category' => $terms,
        )
    );

    $new_film_id = wp_insert_post($post);
```

#### Remark

Rarst makes a good point in the comments which I think needs highlighting:

> wp_insert_post() will check for permission for tax_input and fail if user is not logged in. It's bad choice for non-typical post inserts, explicit wp_set_object_terms() is better for use cases like migrations, front-end submissions, etc

Comment: Hello Stephen Harris. Thanks a lot for your assistance, but unfortunatly still not working. I don't realy know what's wrong. I have remove the wp_set_object_terms, and I use only your way. Any other idea :? Kind regards, Merianos Nikos

Comment: Note that `wp_insert_post()` will check for permission for `tax_input` and fail if user is not logged in. It's bad choice for non-typical post inserts, explicit `wp_set_object_terms()` is better for use cases like migrations, front-end submissions, etc.

Comment: After a deep search, I notice that the taxonomy looks like not exists. I have print out the $wp_taxonomies and the taxonomy exists into that global varialbe. But the taxonomy_exists return false :(

Comment: @Rarst I think that should be posted as a separate answer. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

I found using `isset()` allowed me to use `wp_insert_post()` on custom post types:

```
if ( !isset( $id ) ) {
    $id = wp_insert_post( $new, true ); 
}
```

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answers the question.